# add-pnpfile between powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I got this inconvenience, im trying to copy a file between sharepoint, I already have the file in a variable but when I tried, it said:

```
Add-PnPFile : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this 
action or access this resource.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPFile -Path "http://domain/$cow" -Folder Documents
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], 
ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile
```

I would like to know how i can open two connection, one to grab the file in that sharepoint and then send to the other one.

this is the code I'm using

```
Add-PnPFile -Path "http://domain/$cow" -Folder Documents
```

**$cow** is variable that contiain my file and **Document** is where i wanna add the file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to connect to the first SharePoint first with:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

next get the file you want with:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url Documents/sample.doc -Path c:\temp -FileName sample.doc -AsFile
```

and finally, after connecting to the second SharePoint, add the file with:

```
Add-PnPFile -Path c:\temp\sample.doc -Folder "Documents"
```